# Java Scanner to print previous and next lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am using 'java.util.Scanner' to read and scan for keywords and want to print the previous 5 lines and next 5 lines of the encountered keyword, below is my code

```
 ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();      
 keywords.add("ERROR");             
 keywords.add("EXCEPTION");
 java.io.File file = new java.io.File(LOG_FILE);
      Scanner input = null;
    try {
        input = new Scanner(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      int count = 0;
      String previousLine = null;
      while(input.hasNext()){
          String line = input.nextLine();
          for(String keyword : keywords){                
              if(line.contains(keyword)){                                             
                  //print prev 5 lines
                  system.out.println(previousLine); // this will print only last previous line ( i need last 5 previous lines)
                  ???
                  //print next 5 lines                    
                  system.out.println(input.nextLine());
                  system.out.println(input.nextLine());
                  system.out.println(input.nextLine());
                  system.out.println(input.nextLine());
                  system.out.println(input.nextLine());
              }
              previousLine = line;
          }
```

any pointers to print previous 5 lines..?

Answer (score 3):

> any pointers to print previous 5 lines..?

- Save them in an `Dequeue<String>` such as a `LinkedList<String>` for its "First In First Out (FIFO)" behavior.
- Either that or use 5 variables or an array of 5 Strings, manually move Strings from one slot or variable to another, and then print them.
- If you use Dequeue/LinkedList, use the Dequeue's `addFirst(...)` method to add a new String to the beginning and `removeLast()` to remove the list's last String (if its size is > 5). Iterate through the LinkedList to get the current Strings it contains.

Other suggestions:

- Your Scanner's check `scanner.hasNextXXX()` method should match the get method, `scanner.nextXXX()`. So you should check for `hasNextLine()` if you're going to call `nextLine()`. Otherwise you risk problems.
- Please try to post real code here in your questions, not sort-of, will never compile code. i.e., `system.out.println` vs `System.out.println`. I know it's a little thing, but it means a lot when others try to play with your code.
- Use ArrayList's `contains(...)` method to get rid of that for loop.

e.g.,

```
  LinkedList<String> fivePrevLines = new LinkedList<>();
  java.io.File file = new java.io.File(LOG_FILE);
  Scanner input = null;
  try {
     input = new Scanner(file);
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = input.nextLine();
     if (keywords.contains(line)) {
        System.out.println("keyword found!");
        for (String prevLine : fivePrevLines) {
           System.out.println(prevLine);
        }
     } else {
        fivePrevLines.addFirst(line);
        if (fivePrevLines.size() > 5) {
           fivePrevLines.removeLast();
        }
     }
  }
  if (input != null) {
     input.close();
  }
```

---

**Edit**
You state in comment:

> ok i ran small test program to see if the contains(...) method works ...`<unreadable unformatted code>`... and this returned keyword not found...!

It's all how you use it. The `contains(...)` method works to check if a Collection contains another object. It won't work if you feed it a huge String that may or may not use one of the Strings in the collection, but will work on the individual Strings that comprise the larger String.  For example:

```
  ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
  temp.add("error");
  temp.add("exception");
  String s = "Internal Exception: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object";
  String[] tokens = s.split("[\\s\\.:,]+");
  for (String token : tokens) {
     if (temp.contains(token.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("keyword found:     " + token);
     } else {
        System.out.println("keyword not found: " + token);
     }
  }
```

Also, you will want to avoid posting code in comments since they don't retain their formatting and are unreadable and untestable. Instead edit your original question and post a comment to alert us to the edit.

---

**Edit 2**
As per dspyz:

> For stacks and queues, when there isn't any significant functionality/performance reason to use one over the other, you should default to ArrayDeque rather than LinkedList. It's generally faster, takes up less memory, and requires less garbage collection.

Comment: First, apologies for not placing the correct code/syntax. and thanks much for your help, i tried above code and found 2 issues: 1.Use ArrayList's contains(...) did not work (it never found the keywords) so i had to switch back to for loop. 2. I see duplicate lines printed (2 times or times)

Comment: @aeinstein83: run a small test program to see if the `contains(...)` method works, because it sure worked well for me. A for the duplicates, it could be due to what code is nested in what block. Again, the code above worked great for me. To debug the latter, use a debugger or println statements to find the source of the logic problem.

Comment: if you change this line keywords.contains(line) from the Hovercraft answer  to keywords.contains(line.trim()) the code may work for you, the line may contain empty spaces, that may be the reason why the arryalist. contains() method did not work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i thought that would work but still no luck..sample lines are LINE1. Local Exception Stack: 
LINE2. Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
LINE3. Internal Exception: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
LINE4. Error Code: 0

Comment: ok i ran small test program to see if the contains(...) method works `public void test(){
  ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
  temp.add("error");
  temp.add("Exception");
  String s = "Internal Exception: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object";
  if(temp.contains(s.trim()))
   logger.info("KeyWord Found...!");
  else
   logger.info("Keyword not Found...!");
 }` and this returned keyword not found...!

Comment: For stacks and queues, when there isn't any significant functionality/performance reason to use one over the other, you should default to ArrayDeque rather than LinkedList.  It's generally faster, takes up less memory, and requires less garbage collection.

Comment: @dspyz: thanks for the good advice! Let me edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small (< a million lines) you are way better off just copying the lines into an ArrayList and then getting the next and previous 5 lines using random access into the array.

Sometimes the best solution is just plain brute force.

Your code is going to get tricky if you have two keyword hits inside your +-5 line window. Let's say you have hits two lines apart. Do you dump two 10-line windows? One 12-line window?

Random access will make implementing this stuff way easier.